# how to get response headers using Retrofit in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Hello I am working on async using retrofit and rxjava2

and I have to get the value from the header while talking to the server developer.

However, I don't know how to get the header from the method I use. I know how to get it from Call Response, but I don't know how to bring the header because the method used is different.

my retrofit2 class

```
private val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client())
        .baseUrl(serverIp)
        .build()

    val userApi: UserAPI = retrofit.create(UserAPI::class.java)
```

my model class

```
@POST("user")
    fun login(
        @Body loginRequest : LoginRequest
    ) : Single<UserResponse>

data class LoginRequest(
    val phone: String?,
    @SerializedName("gender")
    val gender: String?,
    @SerializedName("age")
    val age: String?,
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String?
)

data class UserResponse (
    override var status: Int,
    override var message: String,
    override var timestamp: String,
    var data: Data
) : CommonResponse() {
    data class Data(
        var username: String?,
        var token: String?
    )
}
```

my viewModel ( rx )

```
addDisposable(
            model.loginBody(loginRequest)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({
                    _loginResult.postValue(it)
                }, {
                    Timber.d("response error, message : ${it.localizedMessage}")
                })
        )
```

My current situation is as follows. I need the headers returned by the server after login,
I can see it from the okhttp log, but I don't know how to get a specific header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Word of advice rather than a solution

Not a question of solving your problem but even if it's late, as you're
using Kotlin, a better solution would be to migrate from rxJava to Kotlin Flow. It allows you to use `suspend` functions to do your retrofit calls, then use Kotlin Flow to do the rxJava's job on the IO thread.

It also allows you to use the `Response<T>` retrofit object in a simpler way.

### Example:

#### The retrofit request

```
    @POST(YOUR_ROAD) // Retrofit road
        suspend fun connect(
            @Body credentials: CredentialsObjectBody
        ): Response<ConnectionObjectResponse>
```

#### The repository call to the retrofit request

```
    // The function is suspending the thread with suspend keyword
    suspend fun yourFunction(): Flow<DataState<TypeForEmitter>> = flow {
        try {
            body.clientId = sessionPrefs.deviceName!!
            val connectionResponse =
                majorApi.connect(
                    // what you need to put in the body
                )
                    .apply {
                        if (isSuccessful) {
                            body()?.let {
                                // Here you can use what's in the request body
                                emit(DataState.Success(it))
                            } ?: throw Exception("Request body was null")
                        } else {
                            throw Exception(headers()["message"]) // use throw to handle the error in the catch
                        }
                    }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: ${e.message}")
            emit(DataState.Error(e))
        }
    }
```

##### DataState:

DataState is a sealed class that allows to differentiate emitted status

```
    sealed class DataState<out R> {
        data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : DataState<T>()
        data class Error(val exception: Exception) : DataState<Nothing>()
        object Loading : DataState<Nothing>()
    }
```

#### How to call the Kotlin flow to launch it on IO thread to prevent blocking the Main (or UI) thread

```
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        yourFunction().onEach {
            /*
                onEach is like onNext, but emits every type of error, compared to rxJava
                that differentiates next/success, complete and error events
            */
        }
    }
```

Comment: I totally agree, but it is difficult to change because of the uniformity of the codes used by the company. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I totally understand, that's precisely why I was speaking about advising you rather than giving a solution

Answer (score 2):

To retreive response headers and other usefull information you can use the [`Response`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html) type from retrofit2 package. To use this change the return type of your login method to `Single<retrofit2.Response<UserResponse>>`

```
@POST("user")
fun login( @Body loginRequest : LoginRequest): Single<retrofit2.Response<UserResponse>>
```

Now to retrieve headers in your ViewModel

```
addDisposable(
            model.loginBody(loginRequest)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({
                     val headers = it.headers() // do something with headers
                     val data = it.body()
                    _loginResult.postValue(data)
                }, {
                    Timber.d("response error, message : ${it.localizedMessage}")
                })
        )
```

Comment: Thanks but I solved it the same way before seeing this answer lol

But a huge thank you to mightyWOZ for the reply